# Copy data to user selected cell in another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA
I figured out how to copy a cell value from one workbook to another assuming the location of the destination cell is known.

What i need is for the user to select a single cell in a worksheet and when a command button attached to a macro is clicked data from a fixed location is copied to that cell.

I would really appreciate any suggestions...

I need to open a new workbook and copy cell / named range then come back to original workbook and paste in the location that was selected by the user. In case of range the selected cell is taken as starting cell.

Comment: Have you tried using `ActiveCell.Copy` instead of `Range("XXX").Copy`?

Comment: Actually i know where the data is. Its the cell where it needs to be copied that will be selected by the user.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Paste` then?! That's assuming the button in on the destination sheet.

Comment: I thought that would work but since i open another workbook to collect the info..   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(usname).Range("xxx").PasteSpecial works but ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(usname).ActiveCell.PasteSpecial gives subscript out of range error

Comment: if they click you button after selecting the cell, then you can grab the location using `Activecell.Address` and put that into your paste: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(usname).Range(SavedCellAddress).PasteSpecial`

Comment: i used Selection.row & selection.coloum to get the current position and then passed it to the function handling the data copy. Then used Thisworkbook.Worksheets(usname).cells(r,c).pastespecial to paste the  data back to the original sheet.  If there is a simpler method please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I used following method to solve my problem..

I passed the row & column index to the function that handles the copying
To get the cell index

```
Activecell.row
Activecell.column
```

Then pasted to that location as follows...

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(<worksheetname>).Cells(row,column).pastespecial
```